# Python how to print an output of numbers in reverse order?

Tags: python

Im sure this is a very basic problem but Im a bit stuck on it. I have my code shown below

```
user_input = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
positive_int = int(user_input)

total = 0

print("Here are the equations: ")

for i in range(positive_int,0,-1):

 total = (i*i + (i+1)*(i+1))
 
 if(total > 100):
  break
 
 print(str(i) + " square + " + str(i+1) + " square = " + str(total))
```

and the output is correct based on the above

```
Enter a positive integer: 5
Here are the equations: 
5 square + 6 square = 61
4 square + 5 square = 41
3 square + 4 square = 25
2 square + 3 square = 13
1 square + 2 square = 5
```

However, im looking for the following output

```
Enter a positive integer: 5
Here are the equations:
5 square + 6 square = 25 + 36 = 61
6 square + 7 square = 36 + 49 = 85
7 square + 8 square = 49 + 64 = 113
```

so instead of going `4 square + 5 square` on the second line, (IE iterating backwars from 5 to 1) I want it to iterate up, so `6 square + 7 square`,  `7 square + 8 square` etc etc.

Comment: How do you decide where to stop? The best way to solve something like this is to express what exactly you want precisely and step by step, then to write the code you just said.

Comment: its in the code, I have a break for when the number hits 100

Comment: So make an attempt to code it. You clearly know how a loop works. As a hint, use `while` instead of `for`.

Comment: Your numbers currently _are in reverse order_. Look into the docs of the `range()` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need to change the range you're iterating over. Currently, you iterate from 5 to 0 in steps of -1 (so going down from 5 to 0). You want to loop starting from 5 and going up until you break out of the loop. This does not require a range.

```
user_input = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
positive_int = int(user_input)

total = 0

print("Here are the equations: ")

i = positive_int  # keep track of i separately in case you want to use the original value
while True:  # loop forever until we break out (when total > 100)

    total = (i*i + (i+1)*(i+1))
 
    if(total > 100):
        break
 
    print(str(i) + " square + " + str(i+1) + " square = " + str(total))
    i += 1  # increment i
```

Comment: ah okay I see I should of used a while loop not a for loop. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. =)